# How to copy x and y coordinate from one Flex component to another

Tags: apache-flex

I would like to base one component's x and y cooridnates according to another, I tried using the binding notation but it doesn't seem to work!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:VGroup   xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
            xmlns:vld ="com.lal.validators.*"
            xmlns:effect="com.lal.effects.*" 
            xmlns:components="com.lal.components.*"
            width="400" height="100%"
            right="0"
            horizontalAlign="right"
            verticalCenter="0">
......  

    <s:VGroup
        width="125"
        height="100%"
        horizontalAlign="right"
        gap="0"  width.normal="153" x.normal="247" width.expanded="199" x.expanded="201">

        ......

        <s:Panel includeIn="expanded" id="buttonsGroup"           
                 mouseOut="changeStateToNormal();"
                 mouseOver="stopChangeToNormal();"
                 skinClass="com.lal.skins.TitlelessPanel"
                 title="hi"
                 right="0"
                 width="125" height="700" >
            .....
            <s:Label text="Jump To Date" paddingTop="20" />
            <s:TextInput id="wholeDate" width="100"  
                         mouseOver="stopChangeToNormal();"
                         click="date1.visible = true"
                         focusOut="date1.visible = false"/>
            ...
        </s:Panel>
    </s:VGroup>
    <mx:DateChooser id="date1" 
                    change="useDate(event); this.visible = false; " 
                    visible="false"  
                    mouseOver="stopChangeToNormal();" 
                    y="{wholeDate.y}"
                    x="{wholeDate.x}" />    
</s:VGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is due to the container types you are using. You can only specify arbitrary X and Y co-ordinates for views when their parent container uses absolute layout, such as a Canvas. The VGroup has its own ideas about where it's going to put its children. If you want arbitrary control over the position of child components, use an absolute layout.

Comment: Thanks lach...You were right all I had to do to change the s:VGroup to s:SkinnableContainer and it worked!